# How to check a particular event is available in google calendar using gdata iphone client

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata-api

Using GData client i'm able to get all the event from Google calendar, but i want to fetch only a particular event (i.e by iCalUDID) from Google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the GData client, but maybe you can find an answer by reading the api docs and using the examples. Have you had a look at the documentation for [Events:get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)? The url to get the json for a particular event looks like this: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId?pp=1&key=yourApiKey

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but my question is how to get this through GData Iphone API.